# Finding if a string exists in a nested tuple in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

What is the best (and fastest) way, in Python 2.7.x, to check if a string (or any other data type) exists in a nested tuple?

For example:

```
RECIPES = (
    ('apple', 'sugar', 'extreme_Force'),
    ('banana', 'syrup', 'magical_ends'),
    ('caramel', 'chocolate', 'pancake_MONSTER'),
    ('banana',('someAnother','banana'))
)
```

This tuples needs to be checked if `banana` appears in any of the nested tuple and return the location index, in this case `1,0`.

Also, the tuples could be nested to any depth.

Comment: When you say "fastest", how many items are likely to be in each tuple (how many in the top-level `RECIPES` and how many ingredients on average)?

Comment: i guess the location is `1,0`?

Comment: What do you mean by nested to any depth?  Your example is a flat list - you should provide a data structure and desired return value for nested recipes if you want a solution to work with it.

Comment: @Dave -- This isn't flat, nor it it a list.  It is a `tuple` which contains `tuples`.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the *nested* part? When a tuple contains other tuples, does it *only* contain tuples or also strings?

Comment: @MartijnPieters In my case, only tuples. It would be too complex to mix it otherwise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Recursive multi-location indexing:

```
import sys
from collections import Sequence,defaultdict

#making code python3-compatible
if sys.version_info[0] == 3:
    basestring = str

def buildLocator(tree):
    locator = defaultdict(list)
    def fillLocator(tree, locator,location):
        for index,item in enumerate(tree):            
            if isinstance(item,basestring):
                locator[item].append(location+(index,))
            elif isinstance(item,Sequence):
                fillLocator(item,locator, location+(index,))
    fillLocator(tree,locator,())
    return locator

RECIPES = (
    ('apple', 'sugar', 'extreme_Force'),
    ('banana', 'syrup', 'magical_ends'),
    ('caramel', 'chocolate', 'pancake_MONSTER'),
    ('banana',('someAnother','banana'))
)
locator = buildLocator(RECIPES)

print(locator['banana'])
```

prints

```
[(1, 0), (3, 0), (3, 1, 1)]
```

Comment: Better use `basestring` since this is tagged as python2.7

Comment: And I thought I was the only one to put superfluous `if sys.version_info[0] >= 3` to keep backward compatibility :)

Answer (score 4):

A generator could do this nicely if you only need the first match:

```
def find_location(text):
    try:
        return next((i, j) 
            for i, t in enumerate(RECIPES)
            for j, v in enumerate(t)
            if v == text)
    except StopIteration:
        return (None, None)  # not found
```

Usage:

```
>>> find_location('banana')
(1, 0)
>>> find_location('apple')
(0, 0)
>>> find_location('chocolate')
(2, 1)
>>> find_location('spam')
(None, None)
```

Note that the first value is the index into the overal `RECIPES` sequence, the second is the index into the individual tuple; `RECIPES[1][0] == 'banana'`

Comment: This is awesome and clean. But the multi location solution was the desired one. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

use a for-loop to find if the item exists or not, and break the loop as soon as it is found.

```
In [48]: RECIPES = (
   ....:     ('apple', 'sugar', 'extreme_Force'),
   ....:     ('banana', 'syrup', 'magical_ends'),
   ....:     ('caramel', 'chocolate', 'pancake_MONSTER'),
   ....: )

In [49]: for i,x in enumerate(RECIPES):
   ....:     if 'banana' in x:
   ....:         print i,x.index('banana')
   ....:         break
   ....:         
   ....:         
1 0
```

Comment: You search each row twice; first with an `in` test, then with `.index()`.

Comment: This also only works if the recipes are nested 1 level deep.  For arbitrary nesting, you need a good bit more work.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, true but it may still be fast since I'm sure both `in` and `index` are highly optimized. It would be interesting to compare to your solution.

Comment: @MarkRansom -- You can get around checking twice by `try`ing `index` and then catching the `ValueError` that occurs if the value isn't found ... Of course, `except` can be expensive, so that might not make it faster ...

Comment: @mgilson I was about to write the same thing only(`try-except`).

Comment: @mgilson: which will be most of the time, not the most effective use of `try`/`except`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- We don't know if it's most of the time.  We have no idea how constrained the elements in the tuple actually are here.  Although, It does make me wonder why `lists` and `tuples` don't have a `find` method like a string which return `-1` when the value isn't found ... That could push the function to optimized C code without relying on `try/except` which is slow when `except` is common.

Comment: @mgilson, from what I've read exceptions in Python aren't as much of a burden as they are in other languages so it makes sense to use them more often than your intuition would dictate. "Better to ask forgiveness than get permission".

Answer (score 1):

Why not try `numpy`?

```
import numpy as np
RECIPES = (
    ('apple', 'sugar', 'extreme_Force'),
    ('banana', 'syrup', 'magical_ends'),
    ('caramel', 'chocolate', 'pancake_MONSTER'),
)
np_recipes = np.array(recipes)
indices = zip(*np.where( np_recipes == 'banana' ) ) #[(1, 0)]
```

This works for your example because the data is nicely ordered.  I suppose it should be noted that this won't work for arbitrary nestedness as you've asked (but I'll leave it here in case someone else finds this with a similar, more constrained question).

Comment: This is neat. But the data is slightly arbitrary here. I'll gist it for future reference though. You could create a question and answer it yourself for reference.